# Does make sense creating a process from a thread in Java?

Tags: java, process

Wondering if the case2 below code makes sense or not in Java.
The goal is just creating multiple processes. 
For examples, we want to create 5 processes.

```
public class TestProcess {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    TestProcess tp = new TestProcess();
    tp.createProcess();          // case 1
    tp.createProcessViaThread(); // case 2
  }

  void createProcess() throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      System.out.println("start process i = " + i);
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "a.sh");
      ...
      Process process = pb.start();
    }
  }
  void createProcessViaThread() {
    Job job = new Job();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      String fName = "file_" + i;
      executorService.execute(() -> {
        try {
          job.compute(fName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      });
    }
  }

}

public class Job {
  public void compute(String fname) throws IOException {
      System.out.println("start process via thread fname = " + fname);
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "a.sh");
      Process childProcess = pb.start();
  }
}
```

when we want to create multiple processes, we use case 1 which directly create process using ProcessBuilder.

My question is case2 which create processes from thread is common case?

If so,

1) what's the benefit of case 2 over case1?

2) what is the use case of case2?

I haven't seen the code like case2 which creates a thread and then each thread create a process. 
But I saw this code today. so that's why I'm asking.
I asked a person who wrote a code why wrote the code like case 2, and heard that create multiple processes concurrently and immediately without waiting which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not make any sense to complicate the code by using multiple threads to create processes.

> what's the benefit of case 2 over case1?

None

> what is the use case of case2?

If the Java program has to wait for the process to complete and then perform some follow-up, then case 2 have merit.